# greatest common divisor is 7 and the least common multiple is 16940

Tags: problem-solving

How many such number-pairs are there for which the greatest common divisor is 7 and the least common multiple is 16940?

Answer (score 6):

Let the two numbers be $7a$ and $7b$.

Note that $16940=7\cdot 2^2\cdot 5\cdot 11^2$.

We make a pair $(a,b)$ with gcd $1$ and lcm $2^2\cdot 5\cdot 11^2$ as follows. We "give" $2^2$ to one of $a$ and $b$, and $2^0$ to the other. We give $5^1$ to one of $a$ and $b$, and $5^0$ to the other. Finally, we give $11^2$ to one of $a$ and $b$, and $11^0$ to the other. There are $2^3$ choices, and therefore $2^3$ *ordered pairs* such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $\text{lcm}(a,b)=2^2\cdot 5\cdot 11^2$.  If we want *unordered* pairs, divide by $2$.

Here we used implicitly the Unique Factorization Theorem: Every positive integer can be expressed in an essentially unique way as a product of primes.

There was nothing really special about $7$ and $16940$: any problem of this shape can be solved in basically the same way.

Comment: Kudos for emphasizing the role played by uniqueness of factorization.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem. The number of unordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $\gcd(x,y) = G$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y) = L$ is $2^{n-1}$ where $n$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $\frac LG$.

Proof

If $\gcd(x,y) = G$, and $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y) = L$, then
\begin{array}{ll}
   1. & u = \dfrac xG \; \text{and} \; v = \dfrac yG \; \text{are integers} \\
   2. & \gcd(u,v) = 1 \\
   3. & uv = \dfrac LG
\end{array}

It should be pretty easy to see that first two properties are true. The third property is a consequence of the fact that 
$xy = \gcd(x,y) \operatorname{lcm}(x,y) = GL$:

\begin{align}
   L
   &= \dfrac{xy}{G} \\
   &= \dfrac{(Gu)(Gv)}{G} \\
   &= Guv\\
\end{align}

It follows that the number of unordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $\gcd(x,y) = G$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y) = L$ is equal to the number of unordered pairs (u,v) such that $\gcd(u,v) = 1$ and  $uv = \dfrac LG$.

Suppose that $\displaystyle \frac LG = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{a_i}$ where the $p_i$ are distinct prime numbers. For $i=1..n$, let $P_i = p_i^{a_i}$, so that $\displaystyle \frac LG = \prod_{i=1}^n P_i$. We see that finding a pair of relatively prime $u$ and $v$ such that $\dfrac LG = uv$ corresponds to expressing the set $\{ P_1, P_2, \dots, P_n\}$ as the union of a pair of disjoint subsets (where the empty set must correspond to the number 1). There are $2^{n-1}$ such subsets.

### EXAMPLE

For this problem, $G = 7$ and $L = 16940\;$, 
$\dfrac LG = 2420 = 2^2 \times 5 \times 11^2 = 4 \times 5 \times 121$.

Note that $2420 = 2^2 \times 5 \times 11^2 = 4 \times 5 \times 121$. So there are $2^{3-1} = 4$ unordered pairs.

In order to enumerate those pairs, we seek all $u, v$ such that $gcd(u,v) = 1$ and $uv = 2420$. We find

\begin{array}{c|cc|cc}
\text{Partition} & u & v & x & y\\
\hline
\{\},\{4,5,121\} &   1 & 2420 &   7 & 14640\\
\{4\}, \{5,121\} &   4 &  605 &  28 &  4235\\
\{5\}, \{4,121\} &   5 &  484 &  35 &  3388\\
\{121\}, \{4,5\} & 121 &   20 & 847 &   140\\
\hline
\end{array}